# add_filter 'body_class' only working for logged in users

Tags: body-class

The below code works fine for logged in users but not for non logged in users. How do I make it work regardless of user type?

```
add_filter( 'body_class', 'custom_body_class' );
function custom_body_class( $classes ) {

  $classes[] = 'guest-author';
  
  return $classes;
}
```

I have added this code to my functions.php file.

Comment: This filter works well for logged in and logged out states. Guess problem is not here.

Comment: where is this code located

Comment: In my child themes function.php file

Comment: Ok my bad. I cleared the cache and it now works on both. Newbie error as thought the cache would function the same in both states